# How to add a variable to a file path

Tags: r, variables, path, xlsx

I have:

```
points <- read_xlsx ("Data / PC-2021050200.xlsx", sheet = "coordinate")
```

Earlier in the code, I put the date "2021-05-02" which is a variable.
How to enter date as a variable in the file path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `glue`

```
date <-  as.Date("2021-05-02")
points <- read_xlsx(glue::glue("Data /PC-{format(date, '%Y%m%d00')}.xlsx"))
```

Comment: Both solutions are correct. :)

I have one more question, it often happens that I have two files with similar names in the same network location:
PC-2021050200.xlsx
or
PC-2021050212.xlsx
They differ in the time of writing 00 or 12 in the file name.
Can the above code be modified to take 00 if there is no 12? If there is a file with suffix 12, we open this 12?

Comment: @Robert I was guessing your input is only a 'date' variable.  where are you storing the 12 and 00

Comment: The end of the file name.

Comment: @Robert if you have a file name as `"Data / PC-2021050200.xlsx"` why do you need the date replace '20210502'

Comment: I asked the question with little precision.
I have a network location, two files fall into it at different intervals every day.
First the file:
PC-2021050200.xlsx
and later:
PC-2021050212.xlsx
00 and 12 are the approximate hours saved for the location.
Unfortunately, I never know which one will be available. I know there may be one or two, so I want to always open the last saved one.

Comment: @Robert If you want to select either one use `i1 <-grepl('12\\.xlsx', files); if(i1) files[i1] else files[!i1]`

Answer (score 2):

```
sprintf("Data / PC-%s.xlsx", format(as.Date("2021-05-02"), "%Y%m%d00"))
[1] "Data / PC-2021050200.xlsx"
```